# Rails Admin doesn't show gem models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-admin

I have been using Rails Admin in my Rails application for a while now. Recently, we decided to separate our API from our Web Application and we decided to have our models (that are shared between the two) in a Gem.

Now, Rails Admin, which somehow scans the models in my app, have stopped showing me these models in the admin panel (even though they are accessible from the application).

Any idea on how to fix it?

My gem directory structure is:

```
name1-name2(main directory)  
      lib(directory)  
          name1(directory)  
               name2(directory)     
                 mymodel.rb  
                 name2.rb (which requires all other models)  
gemspec
```

Comment: what's the order of your gems in your gemfile?

Comment: Rails Admin, then the shared gem. Checking other way around now

Comment: Didn't work. now its shared gem and then rails admin. Still not showing up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use config.included_models which whitelists models, both healthier and will let you include gem models:

```
config.included_models = ['User', 'YourNameSpace::ModelName']
```

Answer (score -1):

Try making a local version of the model that inherits from the shared version in the gem. Rails admin might be looking only at models local to your app.

Comment: Not sure as to how to add this autoload path, as the additional models are within the gem. Currently, I load them using "include MyNameSpaceName"

Comment: Adding the inherited model worked. I dont really like this solution. Anything we can do using this knowledge (that won't involve me created duplicated models in my application)?

Comment: What is the directory structure of your gem? We might be able to alter it to avoid the model duplication.

Comment: @danielM, that's bad practice :-(